# Grab all rows for a Records where a single instance occurs in a different row for the record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query where I am looking into three different tables and for the purposes of this post I only need to see three columns; RecordID, FieldType and Tranid.  The Record ID can have multiple Field types and each field type will have a distinct tranid.

[image]

What I am trying to do is grab all the entire set of data if any of the Field Types = 'CO'

```
    SELECT     
        Header.RecordID, 
        Detail.FieldType, 
        Header.TranID
    FROM Header 
        INNER JOIN (select * from Detail where fieldtype = 'CO') as Detail 
        ON Header.RecordID = Detail.RecordID 
        INNER JOIN TranDef ON Header.TranID = TranDef.TranID
    WHERE     
        (Header.CalendarDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 10 AND GETDATE())
```

But this is not working.  I'm only getting one row of data back, where as I said, I want all the data for the record, not just the one row.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you looking to get all the data in your tables, but only pull FieldType if it equals 'CO'? If so, change that to a LEFT JOIN, not an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query does not work because it limits the rows selected from `Detail` to these with `fieldtype = 'CO'`, and inner joins to it.

It looks like you are looking for a `WHERE EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT     
h.RecordID, 
d.FieldType, 
h.TranID
FROM
     Branch b
INNER JOIN
     Header h ON b.BranchID = h.BranchID
INNER JOIN
     Detail d ON h.RecordID = d.RecordID
WHERE (h.CalendarDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 10 AND GETDATE())
  AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM Detail dd
      WHERE dd.RecordID = h.RecordID AND dd.fieldtype = 'CO'
  )
```

The idea is to join to all `Detail` records, and then filter the result based on existence or non-existence of `'CO'` records among the `Detail` rows linked to the corresponding `Header` row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the below in the WHERE criteria:

```
SELECT RecordID, FieldType, TranID
FROM Branch br, Header hr, Region rgn
WHERE br.FieldType = 'CO' and 
      hr.FieldType = 'CO' and  
      rgn.FieldType = 'CO'
```

Comment: this doesn't give me the result I need. @dasblinkenlight has the right answer.  thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your making this more complicated than it should be.  Perhaps try the following? I know I've done similiar things in the past.

```
SELECT     
    h.RecordID, 
    d.FieldType, 
    h.TranID
FROM Header as h
    INNER JOIN Branch as b on b.BranchID  = h.BranchID
    INNER JOIN Detail as d on d.RecordID = h.RecordID
WHERE
   (h.CalendarDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 10 AND GETDATE())
    and d.fieldtype = 'CO'
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the result I'm looking for.  This is what I used when I first started and then tried to put a select statement in the join.  Thank you for your help.